# JSON Numeric Keys

Tags: c#, json

Sorry for asking this question again, but I just don't seem to understand the given answers :(

I need to read some JSON using JSON.net. some of the keys start with numbers, eg.

```
"24h_rate":22.65826595,"
```

When I put the JSON into http://json2csharp.com/ to make my classes, it makes it into __invalid_name__24h_total.

I am using the following to read and Deserialize the JSON

```
    public class JsonWebClient
{
    public async Task<System.IO.TextReader> DoRequestAsync(WebRequest req)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync((cb, o) => ((HttpWebRequest)o).BeginGetResponse(cb, o), res => ((HttpWebRequest)res.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(res), req);
        var result = await task;
        var resp = result;
        var stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
        return sr;
    }

    public async Task<T> getJsonAsync<T>(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        req.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;

        var ret = await DoRequestAsync(req);

        var response = await ret.ReadToEndAsync();

        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response);
    }
}
```

What do I need to change to make this work?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with it a bit I found out that the deserializer you're using can't 'handle' key names that start with a number for some reason, even though it's perfectly valid JSON (checked with http://jsonlint.com/)

If you change it to this instead

```
{ "rate_24h":22.65826595 }
```

it works:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public double rate_24h { get; set; }
}
```

---

Thanks to @Ulugbek Umirov:

Your `rate_24h` property should be attributed with `[JsonProperty("24h_rate")]` to be property deserialized by JSON.NET.

Comment: You should mention that `rate_24h` property then should be attributed with `[JsonProperty("24h_rate")]` to be property deserialized by JSON.NET.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I can't change the JSON as it is coming form a device I can't change. How do I "attribute the property"? Sorry, I am new to c#.